# Looping through a text file, while adding it to a dictionary, with word length as the key

Tags: python

Here is the problem.

- define a function make_length_wordcount() that:
- Takes input as the filename in the current directory (as a string)
- Returns a dictionary, which each key is word length and its value is the number of words with that length.
- For example, if the input file’s text is “Hello Python people Welcome to the world of Python”, then the dictionary should be: 
  {2: 2, 3: 1, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 1}

Here's what I have so far:

```
def make_length_wordcount(x):
    filename=x+'.txt'
    infile=open(filename)
    wordlist=infile.read().split()
    counter1={}
    for word in wordlist:
        if word in counter1:
            counter1[len(word)]+=1
        else:
            counter1[len(word)]=1

    infile.close()
    print(counter1)
```

I'm missing a for loop somewhere to actually add tot he counter. I can't figure it out though. Any help would be appreciated!

Here's my output:

```
{2: 1, 3: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1}
```

Comment: Can we see the output of your program?

Comment: Just added it for you.

Comment: I'm using the exact same file as the example, my output should match. It's not counting every word.

Comment: Change the if statement to `len(word) in counter1`.

Comment: That did it. Thank you @Oisin

Comment: no problem. Glad it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a better answer from Padraic, but the only bug in your version is that you checked for the word in the dictionary, not its length.

```
def make_length_wordcount(x):
    filename=x+'.txt'
    infile=open(filename)
    wordlist=infile.read().split()
    counter1={}
    for word in wordlist:
        if len(word) in counter1:
            counter1[len(word)]+=1
        else:
            counter1[len(word)]=1
    infile.close()
    print(counter1)
```

Comment: Like I had mentioned, I'm not familiar with `collections.Counter`. I'm still taking bay steps through Python. This is my first coding course since high school. Still trying to get into the groove of it. My professor prefers our code to be written this way.

Answer (score 0):

Just count using the *len* with a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) dict :

```
from collections import Counter

s = "Hello Python people Welcome to the world of Python"

spl = s.split()

len_c = Counter(map(len, spl))
```

In your own code follow the same logic, forget the words it is the lengths you want to count:

```
with open("yourfile") as f:
    counter1 = {}
    for line in f:
        # map(len,["foo","foobar","barf"]) -> 3, 6, 4
        for ln in map(len, line.split()):
            if ln in counter1:
                counter1[ln] += 1
            else:
                counter1[ln] = 1

print(counter1)
```

You are not counting the amount of times words appear, you are counting the amount of times words of certain lengths appear.

Comment: I would add the open file code to your answer ( using a with statement) for completeness

Comment: I appreciate the help @Padraic Cunningham! I'm still learning and just doing basics. I'm not sure how to use `collections.Counter`.

Comment: @Tabzzy .. I've added the link to `Counter` object, check it and learn to use them.. `collections` module is great to learn to use...

Comment: @Tabzzy, the second example basically uses your own logic for most of it, it just uses map to get the lengths from each word and splits on a line per line basis instead of reading the whole file at once and splitting into one large list,  a collections.Counter is the idiomatic way to do what you are trying to do, I understand this is a learning exercise though.

Comment: @IronFist, cheers, just about to watch workaholics and then hit the hay ;)

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham, Awesome! Thanks for the help and explanation! I will definitely be checking that out!

Comment: @Tabzzy, no worries, using  with to open files  and iterating over the file object would be what you would normally want to do, that is something you should learn from the get-go. Easier keep good habits rather than get rid of bad.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working answer:

```
def make_length_wordcount():
    test = " Hello World\n This is some cool python"
    wordlist=test.split()
    words = {}
    for word in wordlist:
        if str(len(word)) in words.keys():
            words[str(len(word))] = words[str(len(word))] + 1
        else:
            words[str(len(word))] = 1
    result = ""
    for key in sorted(words.iterkeys()):
        result = result + "%s: %s, " % (key, words[key])
    result = result[:len(result)-2]
    print result

make_length_wordcount()
```

Running:

```
python test.py 
2: 1, 4: 3, 5: 2, 6: 1
```